# MVC3 Multiple Viewstart Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I have multiple layouts.

One for my default layout, one for the admin section and one for mobile

Rather than having

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```

in every View, I have a _ViewStart.cshtml in my Views folder with the default layout.

Is it possible to have another _ViewStart.cshtml for instance in my Views/Mobile that changes the layout to my mobile layout for all folders in Views/Mobile

Answer (score 3):

You might find the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) useful.

Comment: I'm doing that but I don't want to add Layout to every single page

Comment: @LeeHull, you could place a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file in all Views root folder and all Razor views in this hierarchy will derive from it. So if you have a `Views/Mobile` folder simply put a `_ViewStart` file inside and set the layout for mobile. This will will override the default `~/Views/ViewStart.cshtml`.